# JObject how to read values in the array?

Tags: c#, json.net

This is the json string:

`{"d":[{"numberOfRowsAdded":"26723"}]}`

```
string json = DAO.getUploadDataSummary();
JObject uploadData = JObject.Parse(json);
string array = (string)uploadData.SelectToken("d");
```

How do I change the code to reader the values in 'numberOfRowsAdded?

Answer (score 72):

```
JObject uploadData = JObject.Parse(json);
int rowsAdded = Convert.ToInt32((string)uploadData["d"][0]["numberOfRowsAdded"])
```

Comment: Nice, the developer of Newtonsoft.Json.  1+

Answer (score 65):

You need to cast to `JArray`:

```
string json = "{\"d\":[{\"numberOfRowsAdded\":\"26723\"}]}";
JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray array = (JArray) parsed["d"];
Console.WriteLine(array.Count);
```

Comment: That is one option but casting to a JArray isn't required: uploadData["d"][0]["numberOfRowsAdded"]

Comment: @JamesNewton-King: For some reason I'd read the question as wanting to know the *number* of elements in the array... and `JArray` felt like the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

I played around with writing a generic method that can read any part of my json string. I tried a lot of the answers on this thread and it did not suit my need. So this is what I came up with. I use the following method in my service layer to read my configuration properties from the json string.

```
public T getValue<T>(string json,string jsonPropertyName)
{                      
    var parsedResult= JObject.Parse(json);

    return parsedResult.SelectToken(jsonPropertyName).ToObject<T>();
}
```

and this is how you would use it :

```
var result = service.getValue<List<string>>(json, "propertyName");
```

So you can use this to get specific properties within your json string and cast it to whatever you need it to be.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast your `JObject` as a `dynamic` object.
You can also cast your array to `JArray` object.

```
JObject yourObject;
//To access to the properties in "dot" notation use a dynamic object
dynamic obj = yourObject;
//Loop over the array
foreach (dynamic item in obj.d) {
  var rows = (int)item.numberOfRowsAdded;
}
```